# Server Side Render Dynamic Page based on Route Param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm starting with Next.js and after going through docs, I cannot figure out how to get the route param `code` inside `getStaticPaths` method as shown below!?. `code` is not known before hand by any means and it can be anything.

I don't want to call api and get the data using useEffect inside the component.

File: **pages/post/[code].js**

```
import React from 'react';
import apiCall from 'api/something';

export default ({post}) => {
     return <>
        render components here based on prop `post`
    </>
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // How to get [code] from the route here, which can be used below?
    return { 
        paths: // NEED [code] HERE from current route,
        fallback: false
    }
} 

export async function getStaticProps(ctx) {
    return {
        props: { 
         // [ctx.code] resolved from current route with the help of getStaticPaths,
         post: apiCall(ctx.code) 
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `getServerSideProps` which works for me:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    return {
        props: {
            post: await apiCall(ctx.query.code)
        }
    };
};
```

But it fails when I do `next export` stating:

> pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://err.sh/next.js/gssp-export

After investigating further on this error [I found this solution](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/11945#discussioncomment-5397), which is not feasible for me as my app is hosted on Heroku.

I'm trying to server-side render the html along with the data based on the route param `code`. But not able to do so now.

Comment: Are you not getting ctx.code in getStaticProps ??

Comment: @pritesh I used `getServerSideProps`, which is failing on `next export`

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the function `getStaticPaths` is to generate a list of paths for which static HTML will be rendered at build time. For example, for a list of 10 posts, you can generate 10 `posts/[id]` routes ahead of time if you know the id of the posts.

**How `getStaticPaths` works with dynamic routes in more details..**

Suppose you have a dynamic route `/posts/[postId]` if you choose to use static-generation you have to generate a list of paths that will include the `postId` as a route param and for each path returned, the function `getStaticProps` will be called to query the data at build time. Example,

```js
// for /post/[postId]

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  // if you know all the postId ahead of time

  const paths = [
     { params: { postId: '1234' } },  // keep in mind postId has to be a string
     { params: { postId: '3792' } },
     { params: { postId: '1749' } },
  ]

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false // we are disabling fallback because we know all the paths ahead of time
  }
}

// for each path returned getStaticProps will be called at build time
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
   // you have access to the postId params that you returns from
   // getStaticPaths here
   const postId = context.params.postId 

   // now you can query the data from postId and return as props

   return {
     props: // queried data
   }
}
```

If `fallback` is set to `false` any for any route path that is not returned from the function `getStaticPaths` nextjs will simply show a `404` error page.

**How to use `fallback: true` to generate static pages for route params not known ahead of time**

If you know some `postId` of the posts and the data for the `posts` do not change very often, you can choose to generate the pages with `fallback` property set to `true`, which will display a fallback version of the page for the paths that are not returned from the function `getStaticPaths`. And on request for the page nextjs will call `getStaticProps` and send the data as JSON which will be used to render the page in the browser. 
Example,

```
// for /post/[postId]
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
   // you can get how many ever postIds are know ahead of time 
   // and return as paths with fallback set to true
   const posts = // queried data from db or fetched from remote API

   const paths = posts.map(post => { params:{ postId: post.id.toString() }})

   return {
      paths,
      fallback: true
   }

}

// in your page Component check for fallback and render a loading indicator
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MyPage = (props) => {
  // before you do anything
  const router = useRouter();

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading....</div>
  }

  // rest of your page logic

}
```

If your data is very dynamic, let's say changing every 30mins or an hour or so. You can choose to use server-side rendering which will `fetch` the data on per request basis, but TTFB(time to first byte) will be higher. For example,

```
// for /post/[postId]
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {

  // you also have access to the param postId from the context
  const postId = context.params.postId

  // query the data based on the postId and return as props
  return {
    props: // queried data
  }  

}
```

Keep in mind if you choose to go with `getServerSideProps` the function will be called on per-request basis so time to first byte will be higher.

Depending on use-cases you can also use static generation with client-side data fetching using `swr` from nextjs team [repo link](https://github.com/vercel/swr).

Comment: As mentioned in the question itself, I need to leverage `getServerSideProps` functionality, but it throws [this error](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/gssp-export.md) while exporting next app. Pls check my question again completely.

Comment: I get that you need `next export` and it's failing when using `getServerSideProps`. 'next export' will always fail when you export `getServerSideProps` from a page, because the function `getServerSideProps` needs a `nodejs` server to run. That's why i was suggesting that if you don't have incremental data requirements you can use `getStaticPaths` with `fallback` set to `true` instead. There could be another solution using `getInitialProps` and `exportPathMap` in your `next.config.js` which I think would not be a good solution.

Comment: Sincere thanks for the answer.
A follow up question to this is :

what if i have 3 articles  in total with id => 1,2,3 
For 2 of those articles, i need to use static generation. => for id 1,2
but for the remaining one article  => id = 3 , i need to use server side rendering :) 
how can one do this.

Comment: For the comment i have posted , one needs to do fallback:blocking as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to statically generate dynamic routes at build time.

To do so you need to let Next.js know what pages to generate, by specifying all `codes`.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    // you don't need here a code from current route
    // but you need to specify all known post codes
    return { 
        paths: [
          { params: { code: '1' } },
          { params: { code: '2' } },
          { params: { code: '3' } },
        ]
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

You would need to re-build app every time you change the posts.

Use `getServerSideProps` if you don't want to re-build project every time. Then the data would be fetched at request time. You can't `export` it because it requires Node.js server.

Comment: How can I implement Node.js server on top of Next.js, and make it export a SSR build?

Comment: @boop_the_snoot, You can run Next.js built-in server in Node.js environment - see https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server.
You can't export SSR build because **Server Side** Rendering requires a server.